# Can I pass my UK driver's licence with my EU (French) passport?

Tags: united-kingdom, driving-license

I have lived in London for 5 years now. My passport is French, can I still pass my theory and practical test here? It mentions needing a valid UK passport or other form of ID. I just want to make sure that a valid EU passport is enough?

Comment: Do you have a provisional driving license? Did you learn to drive in France without having time to pass the test or are you preparing it on your own? Where did you read that a UK passport is required?

Answer (score 3):

I see no problem at all because you are an EU citizen. [The Driver & Vehicle Agency (DVA)](http://www.nidirect.gov.uk/index/information-and-services/motoring/driver-licensing/need-a-new-or-updated-licence/identity-documents-and-photographs/providing-proof-of-identity.htm) will accept:

> - certificate of registry of birth (provided your name is present on the certificate)
>     adoption certificate
> - **ID card issued by a member state of the EEA** (ID cards issued by the UK Passport Agency are not accepted by DVA as confirmation of your identity)
> - travel documents issued by the Home Office
> - certificate of naturalisation or registration (with supporting documentation)
> - proof of entitlement for the State Retirement Pension
>
> **If you are in any doubt about the identity documents you need to
>   supply, you can contact DVA** on:
>
> phone: 0845 402 4000 (Monday to Friday, 9.00 am to 5.00 pm)

Comment: Those are the requirements to apply for the document itself but says nothing about the tests.

Answer (score 2):

The procedure in the UK is a bit different than in other countries. I think it's necessary to have a *provisional* driving license before sitting the test or taking a lesson.

Consequently, the assumption is that everybody who shows up for the test will have one and [you can use that as ID](https://www.gov.uk/driving-theory-test/documents-you-need-to-take-to-your-theory-test). A passport is only required if you don't have a recent photocard license.

A “current passport” is [explicitly listed](https://www.gov.uk/id-for-driving-licence) as one of the acceptable forms of ID to apply for a [provisional license](https://www.gov.uk/apply-first-provisional-driving-licence). See also [UK provisional driver's license without sending passport by post](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/514/uk-provisional-drivers-license-without-sending-passport-by-post)